# Jenkins - Trying to run some git command against private repo that has 2fa

Tags: git, jenkins

So currently I'm trying to run some git command on Jenkins Execute Shell against a private repo that has 2fa activated. Any idea on where should I start ?

I tried using https://userName:password@github.com/path/to branchName however this doesn't seem to work for private repo with 2fa.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your git server solution. Many provide the possibility in the Account Settings to create application specific tokens with limited access that can be used without a second factor.